# crontab - run immediately?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, cron

I have a bunch of cron jobs which run every 30mins.

I'm currently doing some testing, and instead of setting the cron jobs to run every minute, is there a command which I can execute that'll run the cronjobs immediately?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't.

Of course you can implement a different way, not using crond.

You can **wrap your jobs into a script**, being normally launched by cron, which you can therefore run by hand whenever you need

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment.

crontab is executed under which user?

It would be useful to know so that I can set all the correct file permissions etc.

Thank you.

Comment: there is a user crontab, and a system wide one. 

Run **crontab -e** to edit the user's one; edit **/etc/crontab** to act upon the system wide one.

Comment: In general, a simple way to determine the environment in which cron is executing your job is to have cron run /usr/bin/env and examine the output.  (eg, look for the value of USER)

Answer (score 3):

I use this which runs scripts in much the same environment as cron:

```
echo "command" | at NOW
```

Comment: Except that `at` picks up the current environment; also, `diff -u /etc/pam.d/{cron,atd}` shows a few differences.